# Handling unmanaged classpath jars in a library using SBT so that a dependent project can access them

Tags: jar, dependencies, sbt, packaging

I'm writing a library which depends on code (let's call it `foo.jar`) which is only available as a binary jar. As is standard, I'm putting this in the `lib/` directory so SBT will treat is as an unmanaged dependency. This is fine so far.

However, since this is a library, I'd like to be able to publish it so that other projects which depend on it to also have access to the unmanaged code in `foo.jar` without having to manually locate it. I originally thought I could use a fat jar plugin such as [SBT Assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create a jar with the dependencies, but that doesn't affect what is actually published using `sbt publish-local` – it only creates a fat jar when you run `sbt assembly`. Is there some standard simple way to handle this? It seems like a bad idea for every library which uses unmanaged dependencies to break when used by other projects downstream so I wonder if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if that's a good use of sbt-assembly, since other libraries could depend on a different version of `foo.jar` etc.

One way to work around it is to publish `foo.jar` in a Maven repository yourself. Some people in Scala and/or sbt community have been talking about [bintray](https://bintray.com/). It's still in beta, but looks promising if you want some jars published.

Comment: I often feel uncomfortable about putting code I don't (and can't) maintain up on public repository. I either have to list the organisation as mine, which implicitly says I'm taking responsibility for it, or as theirs, which means that their package is online when they didn't put it there (in that form). It seems at first glance that Bintray has this ownership problem solved. I'll definitely take a look. (I hadn't thought about the versioning problem - I guess that's why this is hard to solve in general)

Comment: You could try nudging the author of foo.jar to publish.

Comment: 3.5 years on and I'm encountering this problem. Did Bintray end up becoming the preferred way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get the result you want by manipulating the `mappings in (Compile, packageBin)` to include the files you want your packaged jar to have (`publish` uses the output from `packageBin`). This technique will allow you to include absolutely any file you want within the jar. The official sbt doc is here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Howto/package.html#contents

As an example, consider the common case of including a .properties file within your jar. Lets say you need to include "messages.properties" under the path "com/bigco/messages.properties" in your packaged jar. And lets say that this file is under src/main/scala/ ... You can add the following to your build.sbt:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) <+= baseDirectory map { base =>
  (base / "src" / "main" / "scala" / "com" / "bigco" / "messages.properties") -> "com/bigco/messages.properties"
}
```

To attempt to answer your original question, you could unzip `foo.jar` and add each one of the `class` files within to the packaged jar, according to their correct package paths. So something similar to

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) <+= baseDirectory map { base => 
  (base / path / to / unzipped / file.class) -> "path.to.unzipped.file.class"
  ...
}
```

Or you might be able to get away with simply including `foo.jar` at the root of the packaged jar like so:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) <+= baseDirectory map { base => 
  (base / "lib" / "foo.jar") -> "foo.jar"
}
```